# Could not be able to play single video in web view

Tags: ios

In my application i need to play single video in `UIWebView` i could be able to play playlist in `UIWebView`.

link to get video is:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5cCjaqi31XE&feature=youtube_gdata

here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *videoURL=[self getYTUrlStr:stringURL];
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:videoURL];
    [self.web loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];


    NSString *videoURL=[self getYTUrlStr:stringURL];
    - (NSString*)getYTUrlStr:(NSString*)url
    {
    if (url == nil)
        return nil;

    NSString *retVal = [url stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"watch?v=" withString:@"v/"];

    NSRange pos=[retVal rangeOfString:@"version"];
    if(pos.location == NSNotFound)
    {
        retVal = [retVal stringByAppendingString:@"?version=3&hl=en_EN"];
    }
    return retVal;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to modify link as below

```
videoURL = [videoURL stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"http://www.youtube.com/v/" withString:@"http://www.youtube.com/embed/"];
videoURL=[videoURL stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"?version=3&hl=en_EN" withString:@"?feature=player_detailpag"];
videoURL = [videoURL stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"?version=3&f=user_uploads&app=youtube_gdata" withString:@"?feature=player_detailpage"];
```

Then provided to instance method to UIWebView instance method loadRequest as NSURLRequest.